# Greenplum: gpinitsystem backout script not working

Tags: greenplum

I'm trying to install Greenplum database, and `gpinitsystem` failed.

I want to run the backout script so that I can go back and change the `gpinitsystem_config` file port numbers.

I run:

```
sh backout_gpinitsystem_gpadmin_20160614_152833
```

This is the error I get:

```
[FATAL]:-Not on original master host gp_master, backout script exiting!
```

I'm calling this from the master. Why is this message showing up, and what can I do about it?

Unfortunately, I didn't create backup images before trying to initialize the database with `gpinitsystem`.

Comment: There really isn't enough to go on in your question.  You could manually remove the files and run gpinitsystem again.  That is what I would do.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This would be spawned by a hostname mismatch. What is in your backout file doesn't match what the system reports as the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure about the host you trying backout script just remove/comment first line in bash script generated by GP

[Backout script generated by GP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaTDK.png)